# CSS rotate moves DIV from side of page

Tags: css, rotation

I'm trying to create a side tag, as found here in it basic form. http://www.firstforturf.co.uk/quotation.php

I'm trying to do as much of it as possible using CSS rather than just putting in an image however I've encountered a problem.

Upon rotating the side DIV it is moved from the side of the page. I've tried setting the margin to 0 but it doesn't seem to be working.

If it helps, here are the CSS rules for sidetag.

```css
    color: #FFF;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgb(0,102,204);
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
```

Greatful if anyone could help. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `transform-origin`:

```css
-moz-transform-origin: 20px;
-ms-transform-origin: 20px;
-o-transform-origin: 20px;
-webkit-transform-origin: 20px;
transform-origin: 20px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [-webkit-transform-origin](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-transform-origin). As your element is fixed, you may need to amend the transform origin accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform-orign`:

```css
transform: rotate(45deg);
transform-origin:20% 40%;
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
-ms-transform-origin:20% 40%; /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-transform-origin:20% 40%; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
-moz-transform-origin:20% 40%; /* Firefox */
-o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
-o-transform-origin:20% 40%; /* Opera */
```

[try this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)